# Suggestions for an HTML form input representing time duration (Javascript/JQuery used)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form that should contain a duration field. My question is how to best represent this type of input - the representations I found by searching online looked unnecessarily complex and did not cover durations smaller than 1 day (e.g. two calendars one next to the other to choose the start and end dates, or two input forms that have the jQuery datepicker functionality). Since I am presenting the form in a bootstrap modal, simplicity would be a prerequisite.

The one option that I am currently considering is represented by a spinner for numbers and by a drop-down for time terms (minutes, hours, days, and months). Would this be a good option or are there more appropriate ones that I should consider?

Thank you for your help,
Alexandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a time slider? you could, as you said, use a drop down for the units and then you can use the slider to represent the amount.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use 2 datetime pickers, one for start and one for end

I found a good example about datetime picker [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: This is an interval, not a duration.